# Access PowerBi with BotFramework via Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2

Tags: botframework, bots, powerbi

Im trying to create a Bot with aid of Microsoft BotFramework which can access information from PowerBI. I found some Blog-posts saying it is not (yet) possible, but i was wondering if there is a way to implement a connection via Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2?

So far i saw that one can embedd the whole Dashboard in a WebApp with PowerBI.API.V2 but i couldn't figure out how to access specific information within the dashboard with this API. Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: bot framework itself is just a web API essentially.  You just need to make an API call to the  PowerBI API from your bot.  Nothing would block you from doing this on the bot framework side in that aspect.  Where you might run into trouble is displaying power bi pieces, depending on what you are trying to do exactly and what channel(s) you are using

Comment: Okay i hoped it will work like that.

Comment: But Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2 is the right API to do so, isn't it? I couldn't figure out how to access specific data. E.g. how can i get all information from Stacked Column Chart xy and save it as a list?